# Spray.io case class extraction error

Tags: scala, spray

I'm learning spray.io, and I'm stuck in a problem.. I'm trying to test the case class extraction of several GET parameters. My code is inspired by the examples [from the documentation page](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/advanced-topics/case-class-extraction/#case-class-extraction) :

```
package com.example

import akka.actor.Actor
import spray.routing._
import spray.http._
import MediaTypes._

class ServiceActor extends Actor
with ServiceHello {
    def actorRefFactory = context
    def receive = runRoute(testRoute)

trait ServiceHello extends HttpService with Controls {

case class Color(keyword: String, sort_order: Int, sort_key: String)

val route =
    path("test") {
        parameters('keyword.as[String], 'sort_order.as[Int], 'sort_key.as[String]).as(Color) { color =>
            handleTestRoute(color) // route working with the Color instance
        }
    }
}
```

This code should be ok, but when I try to run it, I got the following errors :

**Cannot resolve symbol as (on top of "as(Color)" )**

**Missing parameter type: color (on top of "{ color =>")**

I understand these errors, but i do not understand why they come...

I'm running Scala 2.10.3

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I haven't worked with spray routing, but shouldn't `as` method be called with type parameter? Something like `parameters(...).as[Color]` instead of `parameters(...).as(Color)` (note the difference in braces)?

Comment: I don't think so Vladimir, what I'm trying to do is to send an explicit deserializer to the method "as", not a type parameter. FYI http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/parameter-directives/parameters

Answer (score 0):

Thats working for me (scala 2.10.4, spray 1.3.1):

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import spray.routing._
import spray.http._
import MediaTypes._

class ServiceActor extends Actor with ServiceHello {
  def actorRefFactory = context

  def receive = runRoute(testRoute)
}

trait ServiceHello extends HttpService {

  case class Color(keyword: String, sort_order: Int, sort_key: String)

  val testRoute =
    path("test") {
      parameters('keyword.as[String], 'sort_order.as[Int], 'sort_key.as[String]).as(Color) { color =>
        //handleTestRoute(color) // route working with the Color instance
        complete {
          <h1>test route</h1>
        } 
      }
    }
}
```

Don't know what `Controls` is, so I just commented it.